# Laravel upload Csv error

Tags: csv, laravel, upload

I want to upload a csv file into the database with laravel but it won't work properly. It get the message

> Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

inside my Controller.

Here is my CsvController

```
public function uploadCsv()
{
    //We are going to insert some data into the users table
    $sth = $dbh->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO products (name, data_required_general, data_default_attribute, data_default_images) 
         VALUES (:name, :data_required_general, :data_default_attribute, data_default_images)"
    );

    $csv = Reader::createFromPath('/csvFile/test.csv');
    $csv->setOffset(1); //because we don't want to insert the header
    $nbInsert = $csv->each(function ($row) use (&$sth) {
        //Do not forget to validate your data before inserting it in your database
        $sth->bindValue(':name', $row[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(':data_required_general', $row[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(':data_default_attribute', $row[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(':data_default_images', $row[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        return $sth->execute(); //if the function return false then the iteration will stop
    });
}
```

My view

```
    <div class="btn-group" role="group"> <!-- ~ btn btn-default btn-file ~ -->
    Upload CSV
    {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'CsvController@uploadCsv', 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
        {{ Form::file('file','',array('class' => 'form-control', 'accept' => '.csv')) }}
        {{ Form::submit('Upload!', array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

And my Route

```
Route::post('csvUpload', array('as' => 'uploadCsv', 'uses' => 'CsvController@uploadCsv'));
```

Answer (score 0):

From where do this $dbh object come from? This is not an object.

```
   $sth = $dbh->prepare(
```

Solution:

```
$to_insert_array = array(
    'key'=>'value',
    ...
);
DB::table('table_name')->insert($to_insert_array);
```

Comment: From the league/csv package